# Update webpage with cURL and flask

Tags: python, rest, flask

I have started learning flask for web development and experimenting with it since I have a website in mind I would like to create.

My thought has been to create a homepage showing some data that will be updated using cURL or the requests python library. I have some other python code that generates the data to be displayed and I would like to use the POST request for sending a dictionary with the generated information to the server and update the homepage with that new info.

A rather simplistic but comprehensive version of what I have tried so far:

```python
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def home():
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.form["data"]
        return render_template("index.html", content=data)
    else:
        return render_template("index.html", content="initial_data")


if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run(debug=True)
```

The code for index.html

```python
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {{content}}
    </body>
</html>
```

So I would like to send a POST request with some new data to the server and update the webpage with that new data.

```python
import requests
payload = {'data': 'new_data'}
r = requests.post("http://localhost:5000/", data=payload)
```

All of the above doesn't succeed in updating the data in the webpage when I send a request, it just stays the same. Am I totally off course? Is this even possible in the way I have thought of?

Any comment is much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`data` is staying the same because it's being reassigned each time as a local variable. When a POST request happens, the variable is created, passed to the template, then destroyed as it goes out of scope.

Try this as an experiment in showing how a variable might persist between page loads, though only until the server restarts:

```py
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

app_state = {
    'data': 'Initial Data'
}


@app.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def home():
    if request.method == "POST":
        app_state['data'] = request.form['data']
    return render_template("index.html", content=app_state['data'])


if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run(debug=True)
```

In that example, you're creating a global dictionary, `app_date`, and updating a key on it every time the user sends a POST request to `/` with a form payload of `data`.

Then, we return the template with the content of the dictionary item.

### A Few Notes

- The implementation I provided would still be vulnerable to [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) if two people make simultaneous changes.
- For this kind of thing, you'll usually want a more persistent solution, like a database.

Comment: Thank you @Ken Kinder, the code with the global variable unfortunately doesn't work. I thought the issue could be with the render_template function, since it actually returns the html code to the call origin of the POST request and not to the application itself.
About the database, I was considering trying sqlAlchemy. Do you think it is a possible implementation to update such a database with a POST request and then obtain that data from the db to update the webpage?

Comment: If the global dict doesn't work, there's something else going on that's tripping you up, perhaps on the HTML template side. And yes, that would be a relatively normal way of using flask and sqlalchemy. There are plenty of tutorials you might check out, but my favorite is probably start here: https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/